# How to make any video Iframe responsive?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

Actually, I am trying to make a responsive video iframe but I can't do this. I have tried many times, without a background frame it's working fine.

```css
.embed-container {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.embed-container iframe,
.embed-container object,
.embed-container embed {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class='embed-container'>
  <iframe src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/vkt0sUM9C54' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: It looks fine to me, what's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code and adjust the width of your frame according to your need

```
@media only screen and (max-width:800px)
   /* For tablets: */
   .youriframeclass {
       width: 80%;
       padding: 0;
   }

   .youriframeclass {
       width: 100%;
   }
}

@media only screen and (max-width:500px) {
   /*For mobile phones:*/
   .youriframeclass {
       width: 100%;
    }
}
```